# HP Spectre x360 How do I get into the BIOS?

Tags: bios, ultrabook

My HP Spectre x360 boots really fast and I can't figure out how to access the BIOS screen?

Answer (score 29):

You should hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> at the start of the boot sequence.

Comment: http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/get-started-with-your-hp-spectre-x360-from-build-2015/ -- This is a blog post describing how to setup the Spectre x360 from Build 2015. Cheers!

Answer (score 10):

On HP Spectre X360 15-bl012dx (2017 15-inch):
Hold `esc` during boot. A menu appears. Press `F10` to enter BIOS setup.

Comment: Thanks.  Many tutorials show `F10`, `F12` but the newer models seem to prefer `Esc`

Answer (score 2):

You have to hit `F9` during bootup. If you miss the right point, shut your laptop off, begin pressing the `F9` key continously and then start your laptop. You can't miss it that way.

Comment: I could not get the BIOS to appear reliably using `F9`. `Esc + F10` seems to be the most reliable way.

Comment: same here. should use ESC + F10

Answer (score 1):

Pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> multiple times really fast at start up will get you to a boot menu, (Just holding down the <kbd>F9</kbd> key won't work) once in that boot menu press <kbd>F10</kbd> and that will get you to the main BIOS screen.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to open the Startup Menu from within Windows.
In Windows 10, click Start.
In Windows 10 and Windows 8, click Power and hold down the Shift key while you click Restart. Continue holding down Shift until the Choose an Option screen displays.
From the Choose an Option screen, click Troubleshoot.
Choose an Option screen with Troubleshoot selected
From the Troubleshoot screen, click Advanced options.
Troubleshoot screen with Advanced options selected
From the Advanced options screen, click UEFI Firmware Settings.
Advanced Options with UEFI Firmware Settings selected
From the UEFI Firmware Settings screen, click Restart.
UEFI Firmware Settings Restart
The computer restarts and the Startup Menu opens.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience Press F2 repeatedly or F6 is also accepted by some HP machines. [HP Support](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00364979)
F10, F2, F12, F1, or DEL. from [HP Store dot com](https://store.hp.com/us/en/tech-takes/how-to-enter-bios-setup-windows-pcs)

Comment: Hello!  Just so you know, this question is from 2015 and hasn't had any activity since 2018.  Please feel free to answer this question, but you likely won't get any reputation from it.  You're going to get more reputation by answering recent questions.